# Arguments passed byReference and/or mutable constant issue

Tags: powershell

Not sure how I can do a minimal working code example here, but I will at least try to explain what is going on.

I have a utility that processes some text files to extract data, and then provides that data back in various ways depend on commend line options and some data in an XML file. There is a variety of "Processes" I could look for in the data, and I can output the final data in one or more formats (txt, csv, xml), with potentially different "Processes" being output to different file types. And since I am processing potentially hundreds of txt files, I want to multi-three this. So I have created a function, and since the mix of processes to monitor and output types to emit is the same for every txt file, which I then want to compile into a single big data structure at the end, I have created that final data structure as a hash of hashes, but empty of data. Then I use

```
Set-Variable resultsContainer -option:constant -value:$results
```

to make a constant, which is empty of data, to hand off to the function. the idea being I can hand the function an empty container plus the path of a txt file, and it can fill the container and return it, where I can in theory use it to fill the mutable data container. So I do a foreach on the txt files, and pass what SHOULD be an empty container each time, like this.

```
$journalResults = Invoke-PxParseJournal -journal "$source\$journal" -container $resultsContainer
```

However, instead of staying empty, as I would expect for a constant, I am effectively passing all the previous journals' data to each successive iteration of the function. I proved this to myself by initializing a counter to 1 and then running this loop after the Invoke-PxParseJournal call.

```
foreach ($process in $resultsContainer.Keys) {
    foreach ($output in $resultsContainer.$process.Keys) {
        foreach ($item in $resultsContainer.$process.$output) {
            Write-Host "$(Split-Path $journal -leaf) $process $output $item$('!' * $count)"
        }
    }
}
```

After the first Invoke the loop produces nothing, but from there everything is appended. So I see results like this

```
journal.0002.txt Open_Project csv Gordon,1/20/2017 12:08:43 AM,Open an existing project,.\RFO_Benchmark - previous.rvt,0:00:22.012!!
journal.0003.txt Open_Project csv Gordon,1/20/2017 12:08:43 AM,Open an existing project,.\RFO_Benchmark - previous.rvt,0:00:22.012!!!
journal.0004.txt Open_Project csv Gordon,1/20/2017 12:08:43 AM,Open an existing project,.\RFO_Benchmark - previous.rvt,0:00:22.012!!!!
```

Identical repeats each time. Even odder, if I rerun the script in the console I WILL get an error saying

```
Set-Variable : Cannot overwrite variable resultsContainer because it is read-only or constant.
```

But still the results are data being appended. Now, my first thought was that because I was using the same variable name in the function as in the root script I was dealing with some scoping problem, so I changed the name of the variable in the function and gave it an alias, like this.

```
[Alias('container')]$parseJournal
```

I then populate and return the $parseJournal variable.
No change in behavior. Which now has me wondering if I just don't understand how parameters are passed. I had thought it was ByVal, but this is acting like it is ByReference, so even with the name change I am in fact just adding to the same data structure in memory each time.

Is there something obvious here that I am missing? FWIW< I am in PS 2.0 at the moment. I don't have a Win10 VM I can spin up easily at the moment to test there.

Comment: Constant here is the object reference, not the object contents, which is mutable. AFAIK this is how constant complex objects behave in other languages as well.

Comment: Interesting. When I try changing the value in the original context it throws the error I expect; can't change the value because a constant, or some such. It's only when passing as an argument that it behaves differently. 
In the end it is academic, because this issue forced me to rethink things, and I realized I had some code in the function that really belongs in the calling script, due to how I plan to use the function in the future. And that change means I am no longer depending on a passed empty container, so the "issue" resolves itself. But I would still like to understand the issue.